# Regex split by space except strings inside single quotation

Tags: regex

I have the following string

`This is some testing dbo.GetPersonData(this_.PersonId,'Date contract recieved from the client') cs.dbo.Person 'this is test'`

I want it generic and obtain the following result

```
This
is
some
testing
dbo.GetPersonData(This_.PersonId,
'DateContract received from the client'
)
cs.dbo.person
'this is test'
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to split by spaces apart of anything between single quotation

I have tried using

```
'(.*?)'|\S+
```

However, it is ignoring: `<'Date contract recieved from the client'>`

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Pzk.png)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and tell us what isn't working.

Comment: Sorry still new to this. I have updated the description @AndyLester

Comment: I think the close bracket shouldn't be on a new line because there are no spaces before it

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried using
> '(.*?)'|\S+

Your try was not so bad, we just have to exclude the quote from the second alternative:

`'.*?'|[^\s']+`
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kSgq9q/1)

Answer (score 1):

`\S` matches any non-whitespace, and `'`, too.

Use

```php
'([^']*)'|[^\s']+
```

Or, if you have PCRE:

```php
(?|'([^']*)'|([^\s']+))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/cCZRFb/1).

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\s']+                  any character except: whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), ''' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following template:

```
(\n.*?)*)\n\s*\n
```

Comment: unbalanced parentheses